# highlight rows on condition

Tags: php, html, css

I have a table which changes a cell on condition. Is it possible to highlight the row on the same condition ?

Please find below the code. Could I change it to take advantage of the css code for hover cells  but permanent

```
$cellvalue = "" . number_format($row[12],0, $decimal_point,"") . "";
$cbchecked = "checked";
if ($cellvalue <> "1") {
   $cbchecked = "";
} 
$cellvalue = "<input type=\"checkbox\" onclick=\"return false\" value=\"1\" " . $cbchecked . ">";

print "<td align=Default ><span id=\"alan_1_invs_value_".$rowcount."\"";
if ( (int)$cellvalue > 0 )
print " style=\" color:#FF0000; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold\"";
print ">";
print $cellvalue."</span></td>";
$intColCount++;
$intColIndex = 49;
```

Here is the CSS reference

```
}.TrHover { background-color: #00FF00;; color: #000000;;
   font-family: Trebuchet MS;
   font-size: 9pt;
   text-align: left;
```

Comment: Instead of applying a style to the tr tag, you should instead apply a class and then define that class in your css.\

Comment: I am not sure that would work, as the tr tag is not included in this code, I already have code to highlight the ROW on hover, and its easy to highlight the cell,         
          print " style=\" background-color: #00FF00; color:#FF0000; font- 
          style:normal; font-weight:bold\"";
          print ">";    

 but I want it to highlight the row permanently if the condition is met

Comment: That would require some JavaScript, and again using CSS classes.